# Read name in excel formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I currently have a data entry problem with excel. I have one exel file wich contains a lot of worksheets. These worksheets contain a lot of data and they all have a different name. Luckily the data I need is always in the same position (lets say D5). So what I want to do is the following:

Wotksheets are: Data1, Data2, Data3, Data4 and Data5.

The analysis worksheet says:

```
 =Data1!$D$5
 =Data2!$D$5
.... and so on
```

but so far I typed the data name manually and since there are hundreds of them I wanted to ask if there is a better way like:

```
      A    B    C
1   data1      =A1!$D$5
2   data2      =A2!$D$5
3   data3
4   data4
5   data5
```

is there a way to fix this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `INDIRECT` function e.g.

```
=INDIRECT(A1&"!D5")
```

or if your sheet name contains spaces:

```
=INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!D5")
```

As an alternative in both cases you can use:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(5,4,,,A1))
```

In this formula there is no need for adding `'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a user-defined function in VBA (remember to save your Excel sheet as a workbook with macros, .XLSM).

```
Public Function sheetNameList() As String()
    Dim returnArray() As String
    ReDim returnArray(1 To Worksheets.Count, 1 To 2)
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        returnArray(ws.Index, 1) = ws.Name
        If ws.Name <> "Analysis" Then
            returnArray(ws.Index, 2) = ws.Range("D5")
        End If
    Next
    sheetNameList = returnArray
End Function
```

Now add a sheet called "Analysis", and type `=sheetNameList()` in the first cell. This will generate a list of sheets and the value in D5 for each sheet except the sheet called "Analysis".